# Building LLVM on Mavericks using libstdc++?

Tags: c++, build, llvm, osx-mavericks, libstdc++

I'm trying to build LLVM 3.4 to link against libstdc++, however on Mavericks it seems the default is now to use libc++ and I've having trouble running configure as it seems most options are defined to enable libc++ / c++11 rather than disable them.

Incidentally the reason for doing this is that I have dependencies on libraries built with libstdc++ that I need to use along with the LLVM libraries and without having two separate versions of the standard library (which I've also tried without much success), I've settled on trying to get all the libraries built with libstdc++.

Following the documentation, I'm using these commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/tools/llvm/3.4 --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 --enable-pic --enable-targets=host --with-cxx-include-root=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1

make install ENABLE_OPTIMIZED=1 -j16
```

However, it seems this is still linking against libc++. Any help would be appreciated?

Edit:

Following a suggestion in the comments, I've also investigated the cmake alternative for building this using the following commands:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tools/llvm/3.4 -DLLVM_ENABLE_CXX11=0 -DLLVM_ENABLE_PIC=1 ../llvm

make install
```

I have found what seems to be a good way of achieving what I want using the following extra flag:

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-stdlib=libstdc++"
```

With so many options to set up c++11, this doesn't feel particularly intuitive, so I'd be happy to find out there's a better supported way of achieving this. If not, I can happily add this as an answer.

Comment: LLVM has been moving from the autotools build system to cmake. You might find this is better supported under the cmake build system.

Comment: Regarding the problems with using two different C++ Standard Libraries: yes, it's never been meant to work, so you are on the correct path (at least).

Comment: Just added a cmake example